# Processing Time for a Canadian Study permit with a late request for a Medical Exam

Tags: visas, canada, study

I submitted my application for a Canadian study permit on the 23rd of March, 2019. I gave in my biometrics which were uploaded to Cic on the 27th of March, 2019. I was requested to give in a medical exam on the 29th of April, 2019.

Initially I had filled out that I did not need one because I was in the UK 5 months prior (back in March) and the application said that if I had not lived in a territory for 6 months or more which required a medical then I was exempted. After I was requested to do a medical exam I got the earliest appointment I could for the 10th of May, 2019. My medical exam was approved on the 16th of May, 2019 and reflected on my Cic portal.

It’s now the 31st of May, 2019 (9.5 weeks after I submitted my application). My processing time was 8 weeks and i’m still stuck on a Background Check. I’m unsure of what my processing time is now, is there some way to have an expected processing time?